# How do you say "coming" in Spanish?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

What word/phrase can one use to indicate to someone that you are *en route* to a meeting point/destination and will arrive within a few minutes?

In english, I usually use *coming*

For example:

- earlier in the day, my friend and I arrange to meet at 10:00pm
- I arrive at 9:57pm (a few minutes early)
- I send him a text saying, "*I'm here.*" ("*Estoy aqui.*")
- in english he would usually respond, "*coming*"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The common expression in Spain would is "Estoy llegando"

Any of this also would work

- "Estoy a punto de llegar"
- "Casi he llegado"
- "Llego en 5 minutos"
- "Ahora llego"

  But the simplest one would be "Estoy llegando"

Comment: I've noticed that most Spaniards respond with merely _llegando_

Answer (score 5):

Just as there are countless correct responses in English:

- Coming
- On my way
- Be there soon
- Okay
- Be there in a jiffy
- ...

there are also countless possible responses in Spanish:

- Voy
- Estoy llegando.
- Estoy en camino.
- Estoy en ruta.
- No tardaré.
- Okay.
- Bien.
- ...

Comment: "aguanta", "ahí voy" (which is sometimes stressed rather as *áy voy*)...

Answer (score 4):

También es posible "Estoy de camino".

Comment: O "en camino"..

Answer (score 3):

It seems more efficient and quick to say, `Ya vengo`. or `Vengo ya`.. for en route.

`Ya voy` works just as well.

Or even, `Estoy viniendo`, but that is a bit too formal.

Comment: Why the downvote (which I cancelled). These seems like an acceptable (if less common) translation to me.

Answer (score 1):

Can use this too:

```
Llegaré en breve
Voy de camino o estoy de camino
```

It depends the country and zone

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at 05:56 pm = llegué a las 05:56 pm.

I gonna school = estoy yendo a la escuela.

I'm coming from school = estoy viniendo de la escuela.

Ahora yo estoy en la escuela, en poco tiempo volveré en para mi casa. Ahora estoy a camino de mi casa...

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are great. I just wanted to give a list of what came to my mind immediately, if I were to hear a friend or brother say it:

(In parentheses are how they "feel" to me if I were to hear them)

- **Ya casí llego**  (I'm *almost* there - feeling of your imminent arrival)
- **Ya voy**  (I'm already on *my* way - feeling of you in motion in that direction)
- **Ya vengo**  (I'm coming - feeling of you coming this way)
- **Ya voy en camino**  (I'm already on *the* way there - feeling of you being in the *process* of traveling, more so than "ya voy")

Adding "**ya**" adds a sense of being already in progress, quick, very soon, or imminent.

These are subtle differences, but by comparing them you can get a better sense for how to communicate what you want in the way you want it to be heard.  Be aware that for something like this, there are going to be some regional differences, as a few have mentioned.

(Spanish: Mexican, Guadalajara area.  See profile for language background.)

Answer (score 0):

In Spain's Spanish, the most usual would be:

- *Estoy de camino*. You can use this even if you forgot about the date and just left.
- *Estoy llegando*. Usually implies you are close to get there.

In both cases, you could omit *Estoy* in informal language.